# Making HTML Bootstrap elements dynamic using JQuery + React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I'm completely new to web development so please put up with me, haha.

Here's a brief description of what I'm trying to do:

1. Make a webpage in HTML, using Bootstrap, that displays lists of items (in the form of a group of Checkboxes, Labels, etc)
2. Using a combination of JQuery and React, make these elements dynamic.

Now here's a gist of how I'm currently trying to accomplish it.
Example list

```
<ul class="list-group" id="PortfolioListOfStocks" >
                <li class="list-group-item" id="stockTicker0">1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" id="stockTicker1">2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" id="stockTicker2">3</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" id="stockTicker3">4</li>
                <li class="list-group-item" id="stockTicker4">5</li>

            </ul>
```

I can statically access and edit a set number of these checkboxes (which are going to be tickers) with this *react* code. Tickers is just an array of Ticker objects, which are just being treated as strings right now:

```
    render: function () {
        for (var i=0; i < this.state.tickers.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("stockTicker"+i).innerHTML = this.state.tickers[i];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So I can edit and access the checkboxes, great! BUT the problem I'm having is how to start with 0 checkboxes, and only add in checkboxes when needed, and delete checkboxes when not needed, **based on the length of the array.** So when size = 3, just 3 elements, but when size = 15, a scrollable box of the 15.

I know I can use JQuery/JS to add checkboxes, which can easily be called. It would look something like this

```
     $('#addCheckbox').click(function() {
    var text = $('#newCheckText').val();
    $('#cblist').append('<input type="checkbox" id = "changeThis" /> ' + text + '<br />');
});
```

**But the problem with this is that I'm not able to create the elements with the Bootstrap format, the checkboxes aren't aligned (they look something like the image below), and the Bootstrap theme is not preserved. I tried to use CSS but it wasn't working out for me.**

*So overall takeaway, how do I make the number of items present based on the length of the array? I'm really just struggling with the interconnection between HTML and script. Thanks for reading!!*

Comment: Instead of writing all the bootstrap components yourself, this might be a nice suggestion: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: Haha, I saw that midway through. I think it's a little late sadly. We didn't write much bootstrap though, Pingendo helped with that

Comment: Could you share what's in the state.tickers array? Just some text? And what is the `#stockTicker` in the render function?

Comment: Hey! So in the state.tickers array, it's just an array of "ticker" objects, which will likely just have a string for the ticker name, and some other data members as well. Right now I'm just treating it as a string for simplicity.

In the render function, it refers to different code. i realized i should have posted this instead. I'll update the original post, because I don't have enough characters here

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
render: function () {
    var tickerGroupItems = this.state.tickers.map(function(ticker){
        return <li key={ticker.id} className='list-group-item' id={'stockTicker' + ticker.id}>{ticker.name}</li>
    });
    return(
        <ul className="list-group" id="PortfolioListOfStocks" >
            {tickerGroupItems}
        </ul>
    );
}
```